# Unable to install SQAOD Python module due to missing release file

Tags: python, ubuntu

I would like to install the [SQAOD](https://github.com/shinmorino/sqaod/) Python module to use with Python 3.8.5 on Ubuntu 20.04. Here are the terminal results from following the [instructions on the SQAOD GitHub page](https://github.com/shinmorino/sqaod/wiki/Installation):

```
isaac@isaac-inspiron:~$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
Hit:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
Reading package lists... Done                         
isaac@isaac-inspiron:~$ sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https apt-utils
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
apt-utils is already the newest version (2.0.2ubuntu0.1).
apt-transport-https is already the newest version (2.0.2ubuntu0.1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
isaac@isaac-inspiron:~$ . /etc/lsb-release
isaac@isaac-inspiron:~$ echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://shinmorino.github.io/sqaod/ubuntu ${DISTRIB_CODENAME} multiverse" | \
>    sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sqaod.list
deb [arch=amd64] https://shinmorino.github.io/sqaod/ubuntu focal multiverse
isaac@isaac-inspiron:~$ curl -s -L https://shinmorino.github.io/sqaod/gpgkey | sudo apt-key add -
OK
isaac@isaac-inspiron:~$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease    
Hit:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease     
Ign:4 https://shinmorino.github.io/sqaod/ubuntu focal InRelease      
Hit:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease  
Err:6 https://shinmorino.github.io/sqaod/ubuntu focal Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.199.111.153 443]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'https://shinmorino.github.io/sqaod/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Here is what I have tried. I edited /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sqaod.list and added the trusted=yes tag:

```
deb [trusted=yes, arch=amd64] https://shinmorino.github.io/sqaod/ubuntu focal multiverse
```

Calling `sudo apt-get update --allow-unauthenticated` after this had the same results as before.

For completion, here is an attempt at installing Sqaod using pip3 instead:

```
isaac@isaac-inspiron:/etc/apt/sources.list.d$ pip3 install sqaod
Collecting sqaod
  Using cached sqaod-1.0.2.tar.gz (25 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.11 in /home/isaac/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from sqaod) (1.19.2)
Building wheels for collected packages: sqaod
  Building wheel for sqaod (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-2kzah4le/sqaod/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-2kzah4le/sqaod/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-84dpn383
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-2kzah4le/sqaod/
  Complete output (60 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/sqaod
  copying sqaod/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/sqaod
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/sqaod/wildqat
  copying sqaod/wildqat/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/sqaod/wildqat
  copying sqaod/wildqat/opt.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/sqaod/wildqat
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/sqaod/cpu
  copying sqaod/cpu/bipartite_graph_annealer.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/sqaod/cpu
  copying sqaod/cpu/dense_graph_annealer.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/sqaod/cpu
  copying sqaod/cpu/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/sqaod/cpu
  copying sqaod/cpu/bipartite_graph_bf_searcher.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/sqaod/cpu
  copying sqaod/cpu/formulas.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/sqaod/cpu
  copying sqaod/cpu/dense_graph_bf_searcher.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/sqaod/cpu
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/sqaod/py
  copying sqaod/py/bipartite_graph_annealer.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/sqaod/py
  copying sqaod/py/dense_graph_annealer.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/sqaod/py
  copying sqaod/py/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/sqaod/py
  copying sqaod/py/bipartite_graph_bf_searcher.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/sqaod/py
  copying sqaod/py/formulas.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/sqaod/py
  copying sqaod/py/dense_graph_bf_searcher.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/sqaod/py
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/sqaod/common
  copying sqaod/common/formulas_base.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/sqaod/common
  copying sqaod/common/version.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/sqaod/common
  copying sqaod/common/common.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/sqaod/common
  copying sqaod/common/summary.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/sqaod/common
  copying sqaod/common/checkers.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/sqaod/common
  copying sqaod/common/envcheck.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/sqaod/common
  copying sqaod/common/dense_graph_annealer_base.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/sqaod/common
  copying sqaod/common/preference.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/sqaod/common
  copying sqaod/common/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/sqaod/common
  copying sqaod/common/dense_graph_bf_searcher_base.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/sqaod/common
  copying sqaod/common/solver.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/sqaod/common
  copying sqaod/common/bipartite_graph_bf_searcher_base.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/sqaod/common
  copying sqaod/common/docstring.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/sqaod/common
  copying sqaod/common/cuda_probe.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/sqaod/common
  copying sqaod/common/bipartite_graph_annealer_base.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/sqaod/common
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/sqaod/cuda
  copying sqaod/cuda/device.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/sqaod/cuda
  copying sqaod/cuda/bipartite_graph_annealer.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/sqaod/cuda
  copying sqaod/cuda/dense_graph_annealer.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/sqaod/cuda
  copying sqaod/cuda/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/sqaod/cuda
  copying sqaod/cuda/bipartite_graph_bf_searcher.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/sqaod/cuda
  copying sqaod/cuda/formulas.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/sqaod/cuda
  copying sqaod/cuda/dense_graph_bf_searcher.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/sqaod/cuda
  running build_ext
  building 'sqaod/cpu/cpu_formulas' extension
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/sqaod
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/sqaod/cpu
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/sqaod/cpu/src
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/home/isaac/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/include/python3.8 -c sqaod/cpu/src/cpu_formulas.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/sqaod/cpu/src/cpu_formulas.o -std=c++11 -Wno-format-security
  sqaod/cpu/src/cpu_formulas.cpp:1:10: fatal error: sqaodc/pyglue/pyglue.h: No such file or directory
      1 | #include <sqaodc/pyglue/pyglue.h>
        |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  compilation terminated.
  error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for sqaod
  Running setup.py clean for sqaod
Failed to build sqaod
Installing collected packages: sqaod
    Running setup.py install for sqaod ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-2kzah4le/sqaod/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-2kzah4le/sqaod/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-bt5462da/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers /home/isaac/.local/include/python3.8/sqaod
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-2kzah4le/sqaod/
    Complete output (60 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/sqaod
    copying sqaod/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/sqaod
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/sqaod/wildqat
    copying sqaod/wildqat/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/sqaod/wildqat
    copying sqaod/wildqat/opt.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/sqaod/wildqat
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/sqaod/cpu
    copying sqaod/cpu/bipartite_graph_annealer.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/sqaod/cpu
    copying sqaod/cpu/dense_graph_annealer.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/sqaod/cpu
    copying sqaod/cpu/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/sqaod/cpu
    copying sqaod/cpu/bipartite_graph_bf_searcher.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/sqaod/cpu
    copying sqaod/cpu/formulas.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/sqaod/cpu
    copying sqaod/cpu/dense_graph_bf_searcher.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/sqaod/cpu
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/sqaod/py
    copying sqaod/py/bipartite_graph_annealer.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/sqaod/py
    copying sqaod/py/dense_graph_annealer.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/sqaod/py
    copying sqaod/py/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/sqaod/py
    copying sqaod/py/bipartite_graph_bf_searcher.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/sqaod/py
    copying sqaod/py/formulas.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/sqaod/py
    copying sqaod/py/dense_graph_bf_searcher.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/sqaod/py
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/sqaod/common
    copying sqaod/common/formulas_base.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/sqaod/common
    copying sqaod/common/version.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/sqaod/common
    copying sqaod/common/common.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/sqaod/common
    copying sqaod/common/summary.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/sqaod/common
    copying sqaod/common/checkers.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/sqaod/common
    copying sqaod/common/envcheck.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/sqaod/common
    copying sqaod/common/dense_graph_annealer_base.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/sqaod/common
    copying sqaod/common/preference.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/sqaod/common
    copying sqaod/common/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/sqaod/common
    copying sqaod/common/dense_graph_bf_searcher_base.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/sqaod/common
    copying sqaod/common/solver.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/sqaod/common
    copying sqaod/common/bipartite_graph_bf_searcher_base.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/sqaod/common
    copying sqaod/common/docstring.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/sqaod/common
    copying sqaod/common/cuda_probe.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/sqaod/common
    copying sqaod/common/bipartite_graph_annealer_base.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/sqaod/common
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/sqaod/cuda
    copying sqaod/cuda/device.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/sqaod/cuda
    copying sqaod/cuda/bipartite_graph_annealer.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/sqaod/cuda
    copying sqaod/cuda/dense_graph_annealer.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/sqaod/cuda
    copying sqaod/cuda/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/sqaod/cuda
    copying sqaod/cuda/bipartite_graph_bf_searcher.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/sqaod/cuda
    copying sqaod/cuda/formulas.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/sqaod/cuda
    copying sqaod/cuda/dense_graph_bf_searcher.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/sqaod/cuda
    running build_ext
    building 'sqaod/cpu/cpu_formulas' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/sqaod
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/sqaod/cpu
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/sqaod/cpu/src
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/home/isaac/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/include/python3.8 -c sqaod/cpu/src/cpu_formulas.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/sqaod/cpu/src/cpu_formulas.o -std=c++11 -Wno-format-security
    sqaod/cpu/src/cpu_formulas.cpp:1:10: fatal error: sqaodc/pyglue/pyglue.h: No such file or directory
        1 | #include <sqaodc/pyglue/pyglue.h>
          |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-2kzah4le/sqaod/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-2kzah4le/sqaod/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-bt5462da/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers /home/isaac/.local/include/python3.8/sqaod Check the logs for full command output.
```

If I could successfully install sqaod via `sudo apt-get update` then I would proceed with `sudo apt-get install libsqaodc`. How can I install this python module, working around the missing release file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQAOD requires Ubuntu 16.04 / 18.04 and Python 3.6 / 3.7. My previous attempts were on Windows 10 with Python 3.9. I was able to get it working with Oracle VirtualBox, Ubuntu 18.04 and Python 3.7.